# Alternative to subselects in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of products delivered like this

```
Producer    Category    Quality 
113085      EIT     05
113085      EIT     06
113085      EIT     04
113085      EIT     05
113085      EIT     05
116159      EIT     05
116159      EIT     04
116159      EIT     04
110058      EIT     06
121570      EIT     04
```

I want to se the distribution between quality classes for each producer compared to average for all producers in percent.
Like this:

```
Producer    Category    Quality     Totalpercent Producerpercent
113085      EIT         05          40          60
113085      EIT         06          20          20
113085      EIT         04          40          20
```

I have this select that do what i want, but it runs for 70-80 seconds on my server with around 260.000 records, which is to much :-)

Do you have any tips to speed up this?

```
select
Producer as Producer1,
Category as Category1,
Quality as 'Quality1',

Round(((select count(*) from base where Category=Category1 and Quality=Quality1 and deliverydate >'2016-10-01')/
    (select count(*) from base where Category=Category1 and deliverydate >'2016-10-01')
   *100),1) as 'Totalpercent',

Round(((select count(*) from base where Category=Category1 and Quality=Quality1 and deliverydate >'2016-10-01' and Producer=Producer1)/
    ((select count(*) from base where Category=Category1 and deliverydate >'2016-10-01' and Producer=Producer1))
   *100),1) as 'Producerpercent'

from base  where deliverydate >'2016-10-01' and Producer=113085 group by Category1, Quality1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can definitively simplify your query. Here is a first start:

```
SELECT
  `Producer`,
  `Category`,
  `Quality`,
  round(100*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base`subquery` WHERE subquery.Quality = mainquery.Quality) /
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base),1)
        AS 'Totalpercent',
  round((100*COUNT(*))/
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM base WHERE `Producer`=113085),1)
        AS 'Producerpercent'
FROM base `mainquery`
WHERE `Producer`=113085
GROUP BY `Category`, `Quality`
```

This reduces the number of dependent subqueries.

Compare it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/689ce/5